# Php/javascript parse the result page of a form

Tags: php, javascript, post, simple-html-dom

I've created a page that simulates a login on a site through a form:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="https:/mysite/login.do" method="POST">
            <p>Username: <input type="text" name="login" value="username" /></p>
            <p>Password: <input type="text" name="password" value ="password" /></p>
            <p><input type="submit"></p>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

The customized form seems to work and I can authenticate using my page.
Now what I'd like to do is to find a method to parse the page obtained when I press the button "submit", instead of showing it. I tried to achieve that by using the php simple dom library, but I'm not able to make a post with it. The code I used is:

```
$curl = curl_init();
$data = array('login' => 'username', 'password' => 'password');
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_URL,"https://www.myurl/login.do");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result= curl_exec($curl);
echo $result;
include ('simple_dom_parser.php');
$content = str_get_html($result);
$link= $content->find('a');
$ref=$link->href;
echo '<div>'.$link.'</div>';
```

I've also tried something like that:

```
$request = array(
'http' => array(
    'method' => 'POST',
    'content' => http_build_query(array(
        'Item' => 'Value',
        'Item2' => 'Value2'
    )),
)
);

$context = stream_context_create($request);

$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com', false, $context);
```

but no result.

Does someone has any suggestion?

Comment: get your curl a cookiejar

Comment: @Soundz you mean add the instruction curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, true); ?

Comment: you should read a bit more about curl and cookies, oh and most sites check the referral url, so you have to think about that too